# Equivalent of df.pivot_table Automatic Wide Column Generation in SQL

Tags: sql, pandas, pivot-table

In python with pandas [df.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) takes an `index`, a list of `columns`, and an `aggfunc`. With that info in then pivots the table from long to wide. Crucially, if you give it a list of columns it will automatically create new wide columns based on the combination of those columns. All of the SQL examples I see though (a) only use a single column (which could be addressed with concatenation) and (b) they explicitly write out all of the new wide column names rather than generate them based on the distinct values in the `columns.` When I try to use a subquery to  create the wide list from the column in SQL I get the error `Single-row subquery returns more than one row.` So for, example, I would like to replace the months in the following query with a subquery to a table of months, but that throws this error. This is an [example](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) of what I'm trying to do converted to using a sub query that throws the error.

```
select * 
  from monthly_sales
    //pivot(sum(amount) for month in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR'))
      pivot(sum(amount) for month in ((SELECT DISTINCT month FROM MONTHS))
      as p
  order by empid;
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| EMPID | 'JAN' | 'FEB' | 'MAR' | 'APR' |
|-------+-------+-------+-------+-------|
|     1 | 10400 |  8000 | 11000 | 18000 |
|     2 | 39500 | 90700 | 12000 |  5300 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears `PIVOT` in Snowflake is similar to [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server and hence does not support subqueries in that form. Consequently, developers must create dynamic queries with procedural language extensions (T-SQL) to dynamically generate pivoted columns.

Unlike `IN` used in logical expressions of `WHERE` or `ON` clauses, `IN` as used in `PIVOT` queries generates columns and likely must be hard-coded in advance to define structure of resultset.

As an aside, being a special-purpose, declarative language, SQL may not be a comparable language with a general-purpose, interpretive language like Python that allows for more dynamic properties of data elements.